# cx_freeze how to include 3rd party modules, ImportError: No module named progressbar

Tags: python, package, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

i came across a problem when using cx_freeze, how to "include" 3rd party modules or packages ? according to the doc , it seems easy but ...
my env : win7 x64 python 2.7.5 x64

here is my setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = []
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ["lxml","lxml._elementpath","lxml.etree","lxml.html",'selenium','jinja2',
            "progressbar"]

setup(
    name = 'myTool',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Brought to you by xxx',
    author = 'tool',
    author_email = 'tool@me.com',
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}}, 
    executables = [Executable('myTool.py')]
)
```

and i had problem including the package [progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/) i installed via pip.

here is my simplified .py main program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

# from progressbar import FileTransferSpeed,Percentage,ETA,Bar,ProgressBar
# print FileTransferSpeed

import progressbar
print "yeah !"
```

with even these two lines of code, after running cxfreeze myTool.py, i still got the ugly missing modules warning

```
Missing modules:
? _emx_link imported from os
? cStringIO imported from encodings.quopri_codec, encodings.uu_codec, quopri
? ce imported from os
? getopt imported from base64, quopri
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os
? os2 imported from os
? os2emxpath imported from os
? posix imported from os
? progressbar imported from __main__
? pwd imported from posixpath
? re imported from base64, encodings.idna, posixpath, string, warnings
? riscos imported from os
? riscosenviron imported from os
? riscospath imported from os
? subprocess imported from os
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platfo
rm.
```

of course when i run `dist\myTool.exe`

```
E:\cxfreeze\progressbar_test>dist\myTool.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "myTool.py", line 6, in <module>
    import progressbar
ImportError: No module named progressbar
```

what am i missing ?

```
>>> import progressbar
>>> progressbar
<module 'progressbar' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\progressbar-2.3-py2.7.egg\progressbar\__init__.pyc'>
```

edit : holycrap i found the reason, i forgot when i installed this package, don't know how to install latest 2.3-dev version via pip command , tried `pip install progressbar=2.3-dev`, so i downloaded the source and ran `easy_install setup.py install`, so i end up with .egg file in site-packages, i uninstalled it and installed another progressbar2 package using pip, interface seems the same,  now cx_freeze works. ( because the package is installed into atcually folders in site-packages, not a .egg file )

Comment: Does the `progressbar` package get copied into your library.zip?  Also, you might try putting all of the `progressbar` packages in `includes`.

Comment: @Seth but i only have one line `import progressbar` in myTool.py, the others are commented out, and because there is a __init__.py , so i assumed progressbar is a "package"?  anyway i've tried putting it and all packages in includes, still the same error.   and btw what is 
"copy into library.zip" ?

Comment: cx_Freeze produces a library.zip file to store frozen python packages. In some cases, the zip file is appended to the .exe file - if there's no library.zip, try opening the executable in a zip tool (like 7zip).

Comment: @Seth thanks, i found the reason why it's failing, my fault. see latest edits

Comment: cx_Freeze currently has trouble finding things in zipped eggs. I've got [a pull request](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/38/finding-packages-inside-zip-files) that will fix this.