# Error importing PIL when using cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, cx-freeze

I've been at this the whole day now and I'm about throw my computer out the window. I made a UI using tkinter, matplotlib and PIL. If I run the code this works perfectly, however when freezing using cx_freeze, I get the following when doing `python setup.py build`:

```
c:\Python33>python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("interface.py", base = base, icon="link.ico")]
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 929, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 235, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 575, in Freeze

    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 330, in _GetMo
duleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 579, in Include
Package
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 288, in _Import
Module
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

My source code has the following in the imports:

```
import pymysql
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
import math
import os
import glob
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import PIL
import win32com.client
```

And as I said above it works fine. Is there a way ta manually do the import or something similar? I've read on many websites that cx_freeze has issues sometimes importing some dependencies of some modules.

Originally, I was just compiling and got that error and got the error above when clicking on the executable that comes as a result. I tried to add the PIL module directly on the setup.py file and got that same error but on the cmd.

Here is the setup.py just in case:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable



base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["PIL"]}

setup(
        name = "Link",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "SLA screen program for CRM.",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}, 
        executables = [Executable("interface.py", base = base, icon="link.ico")]


)
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks!!

Comment: I found a similar error on StackOverflow, and the OP seemed to have found a solution to his own problem. He said that he incorrectly used `pip install` on a version of a package he was installing, and it made the package download as a .egg file, which seems to cause problems with `cx_freeze`. Might not be the solution, but it's worth checking out in terms of troubleshooting.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116350/cx-freeze-how-to-include-3rd-party-modules-importerror-no-module-named-progres

Comment: You my friend, have nailed it. exactly the same problem. It was downloaded as an egg file. Installed it differently and problem solved! You can post it as an answer if you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm glad this solution worked for you! I'll move it here from the comments in case it can help anyone else.

---

**Solution**:
I found a similar error on StackOverflow, and the OP seemed to have found a solution to his own problem. He said that he incorrectly used pip install on a version of a package he was installing, and it made the package download as a .egg file, which seems to cause problems with cx_freeze. Might not be the solution, but it's worth checking out in terms of troubleshooting.

[cx_freeze how to include 3rd party modules, ImportError: No module named progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116350/cx-freeze-how-to-include-3rd-party-modules-importerror-no-module-named-progres)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message and solved it by doing these steps (I'm using Windows):

1. Uninstall Pillow from cmd prompt (`pip uninstall Pillow`)
2. Download [.exe file version of new Pillow package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.4.0)

   In my case I'm using Python 3.4 so I selected the appropriate .exe file for my Python version.
3. Install exe file
4. Run setup.py again from cmd prompt (`C:/python34/python/python setup.py build`)

No more error.